# how to get ParcelFileDescriptor for file content?

Tags: android, file-descriptor

I use eclipse-indigo and `android 2.3.3_r1` and I download a string from a server in network.It is the content of `docx` file.

Can I receive a `ParcelFileDescritor` from it? I guess that `MemoryFile` can help me, because I saw `getParcelFileDescriptor()` method for it [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/os/MemoryFile.java#MemoryFile.getParcelFileDescriptor%28%29) and [here](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/android/android/5/p/android.os/c/MemoryFile#getParcelFileDescriptor%28%29), but when I'm writing my code in eclipse, I cannot find method `getParcelFileDescriptor()` in class
`android.os.MemoryFile`.

Finally this is my question: **is it possible without using** [**socket()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#fromSocket%28java.net.Socket)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getParcelFileDescriptor()` is a package private method,so I could not found it in my class(that is in another package).I tried to access  it by reflection but finally I understand that it return a suitable ParcelFileDescritor,if and only if,we create our MemoryFile as a reference to an existing memory file and in this case we want `File descriptor` from that existing memory file.So this method can not help us.Also it seems that in later versions of Android,this method is completely ignored and removed from class.

Answer (score 11):

```
@Override 
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri){
      File f=new File(getContext().getFilesDir(),uri.getLastPathSegment());
      ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;
      try {
        pfd=ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
      }
     catch (  FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
      return pfd;
    }
```